# Writing french characters to CSV file with CasperJS, but not displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, csv, utf-8, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS, but none of this has to do with the web scraping part.

I'm printing a string (containing french characters) to a csv. When I later open that csv file, all of the french characters don't display correctly.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var content = 'ë,è,é';

var path = 'target.csv';

fs.write(path, content, 'w');
```

This ends up being written as `ï¿½`

Is there any way, in the JS script, I can change the encoding of the CSV? I know about the notepad save-as trick but it needs to be automated. If not, is it possible to do through command line?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback
You can specify the encoding

Comment: @JaredSmith CasperJS runs in PhantomJS and not node.js. There is no such option.

Comment: @JaredSmith I get "undefined is not a constructor" when trying to use writeFile and not write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel (at least my version) needs the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to properly display UTF-8 content from a CSV file. You can achieve this by prepending the content with the `\uFEFF` unicode character in JavaScript.

Here's the full script in PhantomJS for simplicity (CasperJS works in the same way since it runs *in* PhantomJS):

```
var fs = require('fs');

var content = 'ë,è,é';
var path = 'data.csv';
fs.write(path, "\uFEFF" + content, 'w');

phantom.exit();
```

Make sure that the script file itself is also UTF-8 encoded.